# Accessible radio input, triggers onChange event by Space or Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have been reading the [MDN <input type="radio"> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) documentation. I want to make accessible radio buttons. So, I want a user to be able to tab through each radio button, and when they press `space` or `enter` to trigger the `onChange` event and make the radio button selected.

Here is my code:

```html
<fieldset role="radiogroup">
    <legend>Type of radiation:</legend>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="radio1" tabIndex=0}>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" id="radio1"  
                onChange={() => console.log('test')} />alpha
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="radio2" tabIndex={0}>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="2" id="radio2"  
                onChange={() => console.log('test')} />beta
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="radio3" tabIndex={0}>
            <input type="radio" name="rad" value="3" id="radio3"  
                onChange={() => console.log('test')} />gamma
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

But it's not working. I can focus the element, but when I press Enter or Space nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this. If you’re already using native input elements, you are fine!

The misunderstanding here is about how to select radio buttons by means of keyboard: It’s the **arrow keys**.

Users can jump from one group of radio buttons (with the same name) to the next by means of <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Selecting a radio button from the group is done by means of arrow keys.

Of course, you cannot unselect a radio button. But if the first one receives focus and none is checked yet, you *can* check it with <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See [Keyboard Interaction for radiogroup on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/accessibility/aria/roles/radiogroup_role#keyboard_interactions)

You already wrapped the group inside a `<fieldset>` with `<legend>`, which is great! You have labels associated with the radio buttons. Looks like you’re all set!

Go ahead, try it:

```html
<fieldset role="radiogroup">
  <legend>Type of radiation:</legend>
  <div><label for="radio1"><input type="radio" name="rad" value="1" id="radio1" />alpha</label></div>
  <div><label for="radio2"><input type="radio" name="rad" value="2" id="radio2" />beta</label></div>
  <div><label for="radio3"><input type="radio" name="rad" value="3" id="radio3" />gamma</label></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: but here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/accessibility/aria/roles/radiogroup_role#keyboard_interactions it says  Space and Enter keys check the focused radio button if it is not already checked, why is that not working shy is it not setting radio button on Enter or Space ?

Comment: I added a mention and example, try it out! The first time you focus the button it’s unchecked, and you *can* check it with Space.

Comment: great thank you, but if I want to check other radio button and I do not want to use arrow is there some short key, or can it be done with enter etc ?

Comment: The only way specified and implemented in browsers is by means of arrow keys, except for the first time an option gets picked. You are free to implement your own keyboard control, but that would be against standards and users’ expectations.

Comment: sure thank you for clarifying it :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rep to just add a comment, but have you tried changing tabIndex={0} to tabIndex="0"?

found this here: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/keyboard-accessibility-tips-using-html-and-css--cms-31966

If you need to use a non-focusable HTML tag for an interactive element for some reason, you can make it focusable with the tabindex="0" attribute. For instance, here’s a  turned into a focusable button:

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0">
    Click me
</div>
```

The role="button" attribute in the above snippet is an ARIA landmark role. Although keyboard-only users don’t need it, it’s indispensable for screen reader users and visual accessibility.

Comment: This might be possible but is messing with the specification of how keyboard navigation for radiogroups should work.

Comment: If you use a completely meaningless element, you’ll also need to bind `onkeydown` to make it work. And `onclick`, of course. (:

Answer (score 0):

My script to make label accessible

```js
// a11y for label
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label[for][tabindex='0']");

for (let label of labels) {
  label.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    (event.code === "NumpadEnter" || event.code === "Enter" || event.code === "Space") && event.target.click();
  });
}
```